# UUID V1 conversion from PHP to C# resulted wrong GUID

Tags: c#, php, uuid, guid

I am not familiar with PHP code. I want to convert [PHP code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959) implemented UUID V1 to C#. I have tried many ways but it fails. Which part of code is wrong?
This C# code produces wrong GUID `fa570fa10-3b235-472b-500-1ebc212c87e0` with `node` parameter of 138417599493834080 (the result can be vary depends on unix date time). When I change method `Hex2Dec` as written [here](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/506667-hex2bin) it produces `393031383131343830-3234313135-3138323139-313238-1ebc212c87e0`. I have no more idea about the wrong code. Please help me to solve it.

```
public static function v1($node)
{
    // nano second time (only micro second precision) since start of UTC
    $time = microtime(true) * 10000000 + 0x01b21dd213814000;
    $time = pack("H*", sprintf('%016x', $time));

    $sequence = random_bytes(2);
    $sequence[0] = chr(ord($sequence[0]) & 0x3f | 0x80);   // variant bits 10x
    $time[0] = chr(ord($time[0]) & 0x0f | 0x10);           // version bits 0001

    if (!empty($node)) {
        // non hex string identifier
        if (is_string($node) && preg_match('/[^a-f0-9]/is', $node)) {
            // base node off md5 hash for sequence
            $node = md5($node);
            // set multicast bit not IEEE 802 MAC
            $node = (hexdec(substr($node, 0, 2)) | 1) . substr($node, 2, 10);
        }
        if (is_numeric($node))
            $node = sprintf('%012x', $node);
        $len = strlen($node);
        if ($len > 12)
            $node = substr($node, 0, 12);
        else if ($len < 12)
            $node .= str_repeat('0', 12 - $len);
    } else {
        // base node off random sequence
        $node = random_bytes(6);
        // set multicast bit not IEEE 802 MAC
        $node[0] = chr(ord($node[0]) | 1);
        $node = bin2hex($node);
    }

    return bin2hex($time[4] . $time[5] . $time[6] . $time[7]) // time low
            . '-' . bin2hex($time[2] . $time[3])                // time med
            . '-' . bin2hex($time[0] . $time[1])                // time hi
            . '-' . bin2hex($sequence)                          // seq
                    . '-' . $node;                                      // node

}
```

This is the C# part

```
    public static string MD5(this string input)
    {
        // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 crypto = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = crypto.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GenerateGuidV1(string node)
    {
        var xtime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() * 10000000 + 0x01b21dd213814000;
        var time = Pack(xtime.ToString("x"));

        var sequence = new byte[2];
        sequence[0] = (byte)((char)sequence[0] & 0x3f | 0x80);   // variant bits 10x
        time[0] = (byte)((char)time[0] & 0x0f | 0x10);           // version bits 0001

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node))
        {
            // non hex string identifier
            if (!IsNumeric(node) && Regex.IsMatch(node, "/[^a-f0-9]/is", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            //if (preg_match('/[^a-f0-9]/is', $node))
            {
                // base node off md5 hash for sequence
                //$node = md5($node);
                node = node.MD5();
                // set multicast bit not IEEE 802 MAC
                //$node = (hexdec(substr($node, 0, 2)) | 1) . substr($node, 2, 10);
                node = (int.Parse(node.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber) | 1) + node.Substring(2, 10);
            }

            if (IsNumeric(node))
                node = Convert.ToInt64(node).ToString("x"); //sprintf('%012x', $node);

            var len = node.Length;

            if (len > 12)
                node = node.Substring(0, 12); //substr($node, 0, 12);
            else if (len < 12)
                node += string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", 12 - len));//str_repeat('0', 12 - $len);
        }
        else
        {
            // base node off random sequence
            var seqNode = new byte[6];//$node = random_bytes(6);
            // set multicast bit not IEEE 802 MAC
            seqNode[0] = (byte)((char)node[0] | 1);//$node[0] = chr(ord($node[0]) | 1);

            node = Convert.ToInt16(seqNode[0].ToString(), 2).ToString("x");//bin2hex($node);
        }
        return Bin2Hex(time[4].ToString() + time[5].ToString() + time[6].ToString() + time[7].ToString()) // time low
                + '-'+ Bin2Hex(time[2].ToString() + time[3].ToString())                // time med
                + '-'+ Bin2Hex(time[0].ToString() + time[1].ToString())                // time hi
                + '-'+ Bin2Hex(sequence[0].ToString() + sequence[1].ToString())                          // seq
                + '-'+ node;                                      // node
    }

    private static string Bin2Hex(string value)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("x");
        //byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(value);
        //string hexString = "";
        //for (int ii = 0; ii < bytes.Length; ii++)
        //{
        //    hexString += bytes[ii].ToString("x2");
        //}
        //return hexString;
    }

    private static byte[] Pack(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        return raw;
    }

    private static bool IsNumeric(string value) => value.All(char.IsNumber);
```

Comment: Is the PHP code even correct? Your UUID ua570fa10… is not even a valid one. It has 33 hex digits instead of 32 digits, the groups have the wrong size - the group sizes should be 8-4-4-4-12 digits - and the Version field doesn’t seem to be set. Why does it need to be a UUIDv1 and not a UUIDv4, i.e. `Guid.NewGuid()`?

Comment: The PHP code is correct. The incorrect UUID I posted above was produced by C# code